# how to free memory of char arrays after passing them to exec*() family of functions

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-leaks

I am writing mixed C++/C code and making use of `exec*` family of C functions. consider the following code:

```
char **argv = new char* [3];
argv[0] = "ls";
argv[1] = "-la";
argv[2] = NULL;
execvp(argv[0], argv);
perror("Failed to execute");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

I understand that if `execvp` succeeds then it won't return, so that means **I have no way to freeing up the memory allocated to `argv`?** Should I be concerned about any sort of memory leak?

If `execvp` frees the memory for me when it is done, then **in the case of failure (i.e. when it does return), do I still need to free the memory for `argv` myself, i.e. before the `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` line?**

I could not seem to find any reference about this on its man page or anywhere else.

Comment: Just don't instantiate any classes that have a destructor that needs to be executed (to clean up a filesystem resource or similar) in the same process before you do `execvp`. No destructors will be called in that process.

Comment: I've never used `execvp()` before. Can't you just use `char* argv[3];` instead and not worry about the allocation at all?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The example I gave is a contrived example. Sometimes I need a argv whose length that can only be determined at run time so I need to use dynamic allocation.

Comment: @RelativisticPenguin You could use a `std::vector<char*> argv(3)` instead to get it cleaned up properly without having to do `delete[] argv;` if `execvp` fails (if you're not doing that already).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I be concerned about any sort of memory leak?

When [`execvp`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) succeeds, it would have replaced entire image with the `ls` process (copying all the arguments) and memory you allocated will be reclaimed automatically - the image will be torn down. This is not a memory leak and there's nothing you can or need to do in this case.

> I still need to free the memory for argv myself, i.e. before the exit(EXIT_FAILURE) line?

If `execvp` fails, then you may want to free it to avoid memory leaks. Especially, if that process is going to do other things before exit. But free'ing *just before* exit is often unnecessary and even counter-productive in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

`execvp` *replaces* the current process memory with the new process. So, everything in the current process (including its memory allocations) are tossed out and everything is replaced with the thing you are executing.